# Jquery recursive function providing wrong result

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I tried to build multilevel menu structure. For this i create a recursive function for making JSON with all menu option. But i am suffering from an anonymous problem within recursive function in jquery. my recursive function added elements multiple times.

Here is my sample code which describe my problem -

HTML -

```
<div id="div_menu_items">
  <ul id="ul_main_container">
    <li menu_id="1">Home
       <ul>
         <li menu_id="3">Admission
            <ul>
              <li menu_id="8">About
                <ul class="sub_menu_container ui-sortable"></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery/Javascript:

```
var main_menu_list = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#div_menu_items ul#ul_main_container > li').each(function (i, z) {
     var menu_id = $(z).attr('menu_id');                    
     main_menu_list.push({"menu_id": menu_id});
     checkSubMenu(z, menu_id);
  });
  console.log(main_menu_list);
  alert(JSON.stringify(main_menu_list));
});

function checkSubMenu(obj, parent_menu_id) {
 if ($(obj).children('ul').length > 0) {
    if ($(obj).children('ul').find('li').length > 0) {
      $(obj).children('ul').find('li').each(function (j, el) {
            var menu_id = $(el).attr('menu_id');
            main_menu_list.push({"menu_id": menu_id});
                    checkSubMenu(el, menu_id);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

For this sample html code alert following JSON `[{"menu_id":"1"},{"menu_id":"3"},{"menu_id":"8"},{"menu_id":"8"}]`. here you can see the result have menu id 8 multiple times. But this should be only single time like `[{"menu_id":"1"},{"menu_id":"3"},{"menu_id":"8"}]`.

You can also check Jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jdtgewxx/1/

I am not able to understand why this is happened?
Can any one help me to override this problem?

Thank you very much in advance...!!!

**UPDATED - recursion for save sub-menu ordering**

Actually, I have a bit complex level of menu structure. I also want to save sub-menu ordering under main menu.

HTML:

```
<div id="div_menu_items">
            <ul id="ul_main_container">
                <li menu_id="1">1st Mainmenu [order 1]
                    <ul>
                        <li menu_id="9">1st Submenu [order 1]</li>
                        <li menu_id="3">2nd Submenu [order 2]
                            <ul><li menu_id="8">3rd Submenu [order 1]</li></ul>                                
                        </li>
                    </ul>                        
                </li>
                <li menu_id="2">2nd Mainmenu  [order 2]
                    <ul>
                        <li menu_id="4">4th Submenu [order 1]</li>
                        <li menu_id="5">5th Submenu [order 2]</li>
                    </ul>                        
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Jquery/Javascript:

```
var main_menu_list = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#div_menu_items ul#ul_main_container > li').each(function (i, z) {
     var menu_id = $(z).attr('menu_id');                    
     main_menu_list.push({"menu_id": menu_id, "parent_menu_id" : 0, "sorting_order": i + 1});
     checkSubMenu(z, menu_id);
  });  
  alert(JSON.stringify(main_menu_list));
});

function checkSubMenu(obj, parent_menu_id) {
 if ($(obj).children('ul').length > 0) {
    if ($(obj).children('ul').find('li').length > 0) {
      $(obj).children('ul').find('li').each(function (j, el) {
            var menu_id = $(el).attr('menu_id');
            main_menu_list.push({"menu_id": menu_id, "parent_menu_id" : parent_menu_id, "sorting_order": j + 1});
                    checkSubMenu(el, menu_id);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Check updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/xqoe9p2m/

Comment: This can be achieved without recursion. Is using recursion necessary?

Comment: No, it's not necessary. But in question i am providing a sample HTML hierarchy. There are many levels sub-menu that's  why i am using recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sample html this works for me:

```
var main_menu_list = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#div_menu_items ul#ul_main_container').find('li').each(function (i, z) {
     var menu_id = $(z).attr('menu_id');                    
     main_menu_list.push({"menu_id": menu_id});
     //checkSubMenu(z, menu_id);
  });
  console.log(main_menu_list);
  alert(JSON.stringify(main_menu_list));
});
```

EDIT: yes there is recursive way. The problem is:

```
 $(obj).children('ul').find('li').each(function (j, el) {
```

this line in checkSubMenu function is returning all children and is supposed to retrieve direct children only.

Updated code:

```
var main_menu_list = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#div_menu_items ul#ul_main_container > li').each(function (i, z) {
     var menu_id = $(z).attr('menu_id');                    
     main_menu_list.push({"menu_id": menu_id});
     checkSubMenu(z, menu_id);
  });
  console.log(main_menu_list);
  alert(JSON.stringify(main_menu_list));
});

function checkSubMenu(obj, parent_menu_id) {
 if ($(obj).children('ul').length > 0) {
    if ($(obj).children('ul').find('li').length > 0) {
      $(obj).children('ul').find('> li').each(function (j, el) {
            var menu_id = $(el).attr('menu_id');
            main_menu_list.push({"menu_id": menu_id});
                    checkSubMenu(el, menu_id);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. But can we achieve this using recursion. Because i also want to save sub-menu ordering into JSON.